# Finding the midpoint of three years

Tags: sas, weighted-average, cumulative-frequency, sas-studio

I have a dataset which represents the volume of sales over three years:

```
data test;
input one two three average;
datalines;
10 20 30 .
20 30 40 .
10 30 50 .
10 10 10 .
;
run;
```

I'm looking for a way to find the middle point of the three years, the average sale point

the updated dataset would read

```
data test;
input one two three average;
datalines;
10 20 30 2
20 30 40 1.5
10 30 50 2.1
10 10 10 1.5
;
run;
```

So essentially looking for what part of the three years the halfway point of the sales occurred.

Appreciate.

EDIT: what I've been trying with the weight and proc means

I've been trying to use proc means and weight function but it doesn't give me the average point of the three years

```
proc means data=test noprint;
var one two three;
var one+two+three=total;
var (one+two+three)/3=Average; 
var Average/weight=Average_Year;

output out=testa2
    sum(Total) = 
    mean(Total) = ;
run;
```

Comment: Can you please include what you've tried so far?  This seems fairly straightforward in a data step.

Comment: I believe the second row `20 30 40 1.5` is mis-stated.  The rolling sum midpoint would be at 45/50 representing index 1.833. (20/20 + 25/30)

Answer (score 0):

I think your second example is wrong and the correct value for `average` is actually 1.833 rather than 1.5. If I've got that right, the following data step code does what you need:

```
data want;
  set test;
  array years[3] one two three;
  total = one + two + three;
  midpoint = total / 2;
  do i = 1 by 1 until(cum_total >= midpoint);
    cum_total = sum(cum_total,years[i]);
  end;
  average = i - 1 + (midpoint - (cum_total - years[i]))/years[i];
run;
```

I think it would be difficult to reproduce this logic via `proc means` as your `average` doesn't directly correspond to any well-known statistic that I'm aware of. It's more like some sort of weighted median with uniform pro-rating.